# JSON inside an html element attribute built via XSLT

Tags: json, xslt, xslt-2.0

**HUGE DISCLAIMER NOTE:** this only applies if you are processing the resulting html sheet with something that doesn't natively translate HTML entity double quotes that otherwise the XSLT processor should take care of generating even inside a normal double quote wrapped attribute. (e.g. `&#34;`). I of course realized the escaped double quotes were actually working for my needs only after I wrote this up, because the first thing I had tried was single quotes which didn't parse as JSON, and I've run into touchy JSON parsing situations before so I didn't even think to just go with element escaped double quotes, but this may still benefit some other situations (see: touchy JSON parsing situations), so I'm going to go ahead and post it.

concisely: you don't need to do all of this for JSON that will be acted upon by a modern browser based parser. HTML entity double quotes (`&#34;`) are valid delimiters for those (yes, even IE).

---

I'm running into a frustrating conundrum with building JSON into an HTML element's attribute via XSLT (specifically, an HTML5 data- attribute for initializing a slider).

XSLT only processes attributes as being wrapped inside double quotes. (note: if there's a processing flag/directive that can swap this, it needs to be one I can call from inside a sheet, not from the initiating call to the processor, as I have no control over that).

JSON requires double quotes to be valid.

Key processing details: I'm working in Saxon 9.3.0.5 and it's being called and initialized by a system I don't have direct access to modify (proprietary CMS code).

I can probably (?) solve this in javascript, but if there's a native XSLT solution I've overlooked then it would be nice to know. I'm assuming there's not, as there's a [comment from Michael Kay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028446/need-to-assign-attribute-value-in-single-quote-xslt#comment26375200_18028499) from 2013 where he jokes about how attribute wrapping choice had always been immutable because there should have been no earthly reason to *need* to change it. I normally would have agreed until now, where I actually do *need* it because single quotes for the JSON inside the double quoted attribute is actually invalid JSON. **edit:** see the disclaimer, he's still probably right for 99% of even JSON related cases.

I could probably build a separate JSON string in a script element or similar, and then inject it into the attribute via javascript before the related slider function gets run on this, and that's probably what I *should* do when I refactor this, but I'd like to know what other options are out there, if any.

I'm going to leave this with the not really native/proper XSLT solution that works in a pinch for anyone else who runs into a similar problem, but I **really** want something better if it's out there, as I hate using this type of hack in XSL.

Example code (minus a lot of surrounding matches, the identity xform, etc):

(the issue is specific to adding the 'data-slick' attribute to the matched ul like this)

```
<xsl:template match="mus:call-template[@name='slick-slider-carousel']//ul">
    <xsl:param name="slider-options" tunnel="yes" />
    <xsl:param name="pcf-context" tunnel="yes" />
    <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@attribute" />
        <xsl:attribute name="data-slick"><xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$slider-options" />
            <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$pcf-context/gallery/images/image" mode="slick-slider">
            <xsl:with-param name="asset-id" select="$pcf-context/gallery/@asset-id" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Example html layout sheet:

```
    <mus:call-template name="slick-slider-carousel">
        <div class="image-carousel">
            <ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </mus:call-template>
```

Example tree fragment loaded into $pcf-context from content sheet (via an xsl:sequence):

```
<gallery created="2015-03-25T21:18:20Z" forceCrop="false" modified="2015-03-25T21:19:31Z" asset_id="649">
  <name>Test</name>
  <thumbnailWidth>100</thumbnailWidth>
  <thumbnailHeight>100</thumbnailHeight>
  <forceCrop>false</forceCrop>
  <advanced>
  </advanced>
  <images>
    <image created="2015-03-25T21:18:53Z" modified="2015-03-25T21:18:53Z" staging_url="[full-url]/6d640b3f-7e50-4bdf-802d-2d5e33955ed1.jpeg" url="[full-url]/6d640b3f-7e50-4bdf-802d-2d5e33955ed1.jpeg" status="existing">
      <storedName>6d640b3f-7e50-4bdf-802d-2d5e33955ed1.jpeg</storedName>
      <friendlyName>d01454b9-5eab-4a7f-b999-3ec92313b193.jpeg</friendlyName>
      <thumbnail staging_url="[full-url]/thumb/6d640b3f-7e50-4bdf-802d-2d5e33955ed1.jpeg" url="[full-url]/6d640b3f-7e50-4bdf-802d-2d5e33955ed1.jpeg">
        <width>100</width>
        <height>100</height>
      </thumbnail>
      <title>A very cute puppy</title>
      <description>Cute puppy</description>
      <caption>Look at that cute puppy! lorem ipsum blah blah blah</caption>
      <link>
      </link>
    </image>
  </images>
</gallery>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Build the HTML element with attribute(s) structure manually (using single quote outer wrapping delimiters on the attribute values)

This is a hack, because instead of generating elements in the result tree it generates text that act as DOM nodes when the output sheet is loaded by a browser… but these are **still not actually elements within the XSLT processor**. I really don't recommend you use this method except when you *absolutely* require it:

```
<xsl:template match="mus:call-template[@name='slick-slider-carousel']//ul">
    <xsl:param name="slider-options" tunnel="yes" />
    <xsl:param name="pcf-context" tunnel="yes" />
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;ul</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="attribute()" mode="textify" />
        <xsl:text> data-slick='{</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$slider-options" />
        <xsl:text>}'</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$pcf-context/gallery/images/image" mode="slick-slider">
            <xsl:with-param name="asset-id" select="$pcf-context/gallery/@asset-id" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/ul&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="attribute()" mode="textify">
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
    <xsl:text>='</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Points to pay attention to:

1. `disable-output-escaping`: You need this on the text nodes that are going to generate the html element(s), or more specifically on their open and closing square brackets (lt and gt).
2. If you use apply-templates within this, be **very** aware of how the results will interact. For example, any attribute templates (via identity transform, etc) that try to add their attribute to the current element will either fail or add it to the parent element, because the html element being created here is not actually an XSLT element, and not a valid target to attach an attribute to. You need to have an alternate mode match that dumps them into text instead of manipulating them as nodes if you want to use apply-templates (see the included example with the "textify" mode for attributes).
3. In line with 2, any attributes you wish to add must be built manually. Pay attention to spaces! (see the building of @data-slick in the main match here)
4. Use `<xsl:text>` to your advantage: if used correctly, this will allow you to give your code some linespacing inbetween xsl:text elements that will make it much more legible than just a single `<xsl:value-of select="concat(stuff, more stuff, too much more stuff, etc)" />`
5. (personal preference) If you are going to carry forward attributes already present (identity transform style), use a modal `apply-templates` rather than a `for-each`. It's not only cleaner and more of a declarative paradigm, but it's also more re-usable. Be aware that if any attributes you are building manually are present already, you will need to provide a logic path that either excludes them (such as a template match specific to that attribute that drops it) or provides a way to either manually add them if not present or append their information if they are (multiple ways this could be done, I still personally feel an `apply-templates` approach to attribute handling makes this cleaner for most of them).